# C++ double is either 1079574528 or 0

Tags: c++

my code looks like this:

```
// in Player.cpp
Player::Player() {
    hp = 100;
    pos = vec(50, 50);
    printf("created player with %d hp on %d:%d\n", hp, pos.x, pos.y);
}

// in Game.h
Player *player;

// in Game.cpp
player = new Player();
```

And the output is always "created player with 0 hp on 1079574528:0"
However the x and y positions are correct when the game runs.

Comment: Please show definitions of `pos.x` and `pos.y`. `%d` is a format specifier for integers, for doubles use `%g` or `%f`. Or throw away `printf` and use `std::cout` which is typesafe

Comment: %d expects an int.  You've provided pos.x and pos.y, which are presumably doubles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting the output because you are using `%d` for a double in `printf()`. You should be using `%f`

If you use `%f`, you will get the right output ( assuming `pos = vec(50, 50);` does not cause any problems ).

Also, since you are on c++ , you could just use

```
std::cout << "created player with " << hp << " hp on " << pos.x << " : " << pos.y << std::endl ;
```

Comment: can anyone specify if there's something wrong in this answer, it sees to have gotten a few down votes. Did I miss something?

Comment: I don't see anything glaringly wrong. I would argue that this is a case where printf looks a little neater, but I don't think it's more correct given he's using c++.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're writing in C++, use C++.

```
Player::Player() {
    hp = 100;
    pos = vec(50, 50);
    std::cout << "created player with hp=" << hp << " on X:" << pos.x << ",Y:" << pos.y << std::endl;
}
```